# New row on top of the last row created in vba

Tags: excel, vba, userform

i have the following issue. I have a columns with a date and time in hh:mm:ss format on all the "E" column cells. The problem is that i tried the following macro to sort the latest record first and leave the old at last, to keep a record of all the new entries of the day.

The problem is that is not working. I tried also doing `Cells("2:2").Insert` before adding the data to each cell on the new row but did not work either. I will leave my whole code here:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then

'Encontrar el legajo en la lista
row = Me.TextBox1.Value
Set FindRow = Hoja2.Range("B:B").Find(What:=row, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set AddMe = Hoja3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set AddMe2 = Hoja3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Set AddMe3 = Hoja3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)

'Encontrar el WT en la lista
wtrow = Me.TextBox2.Value
Set FindRow2 = Hoja4.Range("D:D").Find(What:=wtrow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set AddWT = Hoja3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)

'Agregar la fecha y hora a la celda
Status = Now
Set Estado = Hoja3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4)

'Agregar la palabra entregado a la celda
Status2 = "Entregado"
Set Estado2 = Hoja3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 5)

With Registros
'Si lo encuentra, agregarlo a la planilla
'Range("2:2").Insert
AddMe.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
AddMe2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
AddMe3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
AddWT.Value = FindRow2.Offset(0, 0).Value
Estado.Value = Status
Estado2.Value = Status2
End With

'Sort by Date
Hoja3.Select
With Registros
Hoja3.Range("E2:E1000").Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
End With

ElseIf Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then

MsgBox "El legajo no puede estar vacio"

Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "Los datos fueron corroborados, puede entregar el WT"

'Deja las casillas vacias cuando termina
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""

'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
   ' Verify the data entered, because they are not correct
    MsgBox "Error! Verificar los datos ingresados, porque no son correctos!" & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Sorry that some text is on Spanish, but i want just a simple code to add some data so when i search a specific value, it searches the last values enter and not the oldest ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood you right. 
But, if you want to sort the **Entire worksheet** based on the column `E`, you need to use the range of the entire worksheet, instead of only the column E.

So it should look like:

```
Hoja3.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
```

What you have now will only sort the column `E`

Sorry if this is not what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I have messed up the concept of sort which i thought the way i did it, it sorted all the worksheet and not only the single column, which that is what happened to me now that i recall.